# Randomly Connected Graph Generator

Tags: c#, algorithm, random, graph

I'm trying to generate a simple graph by randomly connecting N nodes. I'm looking for efficient algorithm to do so, something like this:

- Input:

  - `N` number of nodes
  - `E` number of edges from `N-1` to `N(N-1)/2`
- Output: Simple Connected graph with N vertices and E edges

Comment: Where is the problem? What statistical properties?

Comment: The problem is I'm looking for efficient algorithm to do so, something like this: Input -N- number of nodes -E- number of edges from (N-1 to N(N-1)/2) Output: Simple Connected graph with N vertices and E edges

Comment: @darksphere there is [edit] button next to the question - please check it out and update post with requirements instead of adding them as comment (that still not enough to avoid downvotes due to lack of demonstrated research, but at least post will resemble reasonable question)

Comment: As asked, your question is at best far too broad, and at worst does not contain enough information to know what you really want to do. _Maybe_ you can find some useful information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm. I.e. a maze of the types generated by basic algorithms is essentially a randomly generated graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of `N` nodes. [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) the array. Scan the array and create an edge for each pair of nodes that are adjacent in the array. The result is a connected graph with `N-1` edges.

If the number of additional edges is small, then you can just randomly add edges till you have enough. Otherwise, create an array of the unused edges, Fisher-Yates shuffle the array, and take the first `(E - (N-1))` edges from the array.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an extremely simple algorithm which randomly connects each node with a random number of other nodes.

```
void CreateRandomGraph(IList<Node> nodes, int maxConnections)
{
    var rnd = new Random();

    foreach (Node node in nodes)
    {
        int numConnections = (int)(rnd.NextDouble() * maxConnections);
        for (int i = 0; i < numConnections; i++)
        {
            //Find a random node to connect to
            int idx = (int)(rnd.NextDouble() * nodes.Count);
            node.ConnectTo(nodes[idx]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all - based on current text or the post OP is looking for connected graph - adding random edges does not guarantee that property.